# How to calculate the rolling standard deviation by group per row?

Tags: pandas, numpy, group-by, std, standard-deviation

I am trying to calculate the standard devition by group (category) for the last 4 month (rolling) per date.

The following code seems not to work and I can't find any solution in the forum. I would be happy about help. Thanks in advance.

```
df['std'] = df.groupby(['date', 'category').std()
```

[image: Example of DataFrame]

Comment: `df.groupby(['date', 'category')['yield'].rolling(4).std()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i get following error: "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" using this: `df.groupby(['date', 'category']['yield']).rolling(4).std()`. Any ideas?

Comment: You got the bracket wrong: `df.groupby(['date', 'category'])['yield'].rolling(4).std()`

Comment: Ah ok. This changes the error :-D "TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index"

Comment: Just print the part I give you. You need to drop some (2) index levels since you groupby 2 columns.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your support!